# Program using Access DB crashes on db.Close() after a big query. No error message

Tags: .net, database, odbc, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010

I have this odd error that only seems to come up after a big query (i.e., with many joins) and not happen on small queries on a single table.

Here is my set up:

1. VB .NET 3.5 application
2. Connects to an Access database using the following connection statement:

   `Me.connection = "Provider=Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
           "User ID=Admin;" & _
           "Data Source=" & ACCESS07_CONNECTION_STRING & ";" & _
           "Mode=Read|Write;Extended Properties="""";Jet OLEDB:System Database="""";Jet OLEDB:Registry Path="""";Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=5;Jet OLEDB:Database Locking Mode=0;Jet OLEDB:Global Partial Bulk Ops=2;Jet OLEDB:Global Bulk Transactions=1;Jet OLEDB:New Database Password="""";Jet OLEDB:Create System Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Encrypt Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Don't Copy Locale on Compact=False;Jet OLEDB:Compact Without Replica Repair=False;Jet OLEDB:SFP=False"`
3. (Full lines of code is at bottom)
4. The database is an Access file on a shared network drive (we all use the same one).
5. Runs on Windows XP,7 32 and 64bit Office 2007 or 2010.

However, only on my machine, the code crashes after a "big" query. By big, I mean many joins are involved. Smaller, single table select queries run fine.

And to make it more confusing, the crash happens on the `db.Close()` line! The resultset is returned and no error message appears. Visual Studio can't even JIT debug it...

My current theory is something is off with my particular Access Drivers? If so, how can I swap them? I have someone else on my team who uses Office 2010 on Windows 7 64bit so I got to assume I can swap driver DLL's with him (assuming this is even the problem)?

I am reluctant to make code changes because this works on every machine but mine.

---

```
Dim db As New ADODB.Connection
Me.connection = "Provider=Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
        "User ID=Admin;" & _
        "Data Source=" & ACCESS07_CONNECTION_STRING & ";" & _
        "Mode=Read|Write;Extended Properties="""";Jet OLEDB:System Database="""";Jet OLEDB:Registry Path="""";Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=5;Jet OLEDB:Database Locking Mode=0;Jet OLEDB:Global Partial Bulk Ops=2;Jet OLEDB:Global Bulk Transactions=1;Jet OLEDB:New Database Password="""";Jet OLEDB:Create System Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Encrypt Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Don't Copy Locale on Compact=False;Jet OLEDB:Compact Without Replica Repair=False;Jet OLEDB:SFP=False"
Try
    db.Open(Me.connection)
Catch ex As Exception

    receivedCOMException()
    Return Nothing
    Exit Function

End Try



Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
rs.CursorLocation = ADODB.CursorLocationEnum.adUseClient
rs.Open(p_sql_query, db)
'Debug.Print(Me.sql_query)
mpet_rs = New DBRecordSet(rs)
rs.Close()
db.Close()
rs = Nothing
db = Nothing
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer - as sad as it turns out to be, I reinstalled Access 2010 and now the problem is gone. Something was bad with my drivers.